# Lim Sup Calculation: $\limsup_{n\to\infty} b^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponentiation, limsup-and-liminf

I want to calculate $\lim \sup b^n$, where $b$ is some nonnegative number.

Now, if $0 \le b \le 1$, I expect the lim sup to be $0$, because these numbers are getting tinier and tinier, and we are taking the supremum of all these tiny numbers approaching zero. When $b > 1$, I expect lim sup to be infinity. However, I haven't done many calculations with lim sups, so I am having difficulty.

Note, I am permitted to assume any ideas coming from a course on real analysis, so we don't necessarily have to use the original definition of lim sup.

**EDIT:**

Here is a proof of $\lim \inf b^n = 0$ when $0 \le b < 1$.

If $0 \le b \le 1$, then $0 \le b^n \le 1$, and we know it is a bounded convergent sequence. Now, we have that

$0 \le \inf \{ b^k ~|~ k \ge n \} \le b^n \le 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

which means we can say something about the limit of these two sequences---namely, that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf \{ b^k ~|~ k \ge n \} \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b^n$,

or

$\lim \inf b^n \le 0$,

which means $\lim \inf b^n = 0$.

Does this seem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\limsup=\liminf=\lim$ if the limit exists.

Comment: So, since the limit of $b^n$ exists---specifically, it is $0$---, then $\lim \sup b^n= \lim \inf b^n$, and the claim is $\lim \inf b^n = 0$? Is only for the $0 \le b \le 1$ case?

Comment: Yup, as long as $|b|<1$, be careful of the $b=1$ case as well

Comment: Won't the $\lim \sup b^n = 1$ for the $b=1$ case, because $b^n =1$ for all $n$? In other words, $b^n = 1$ for all $n$ means it is the constant sequence. Now, for the $b > 1$, $b^n$ diverges, does this immediately imply  that $\lim \sup b^n = \infty$, or do I have to use some fact?

Comment: Hi, I made an edit to my post, in which I prove $\lim \inf b^n = 0$. Would you mind checking for correctness?

Comment: looks fine to me! also you are correct on $b=1$, it's just a sequence of 1's right?

Comment: Yes! Glad to know my $\lim \inf$ proof is right. And yes, it will be just a sequence of $1$'s. Thank you so much!!!